# remember me for laravel5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, remember-me

Hello guys I want to make the remember me checkbox and I want to save the user info into cookies so next time when try to login he find the user name and password in their fields I try to use :

```
$rememberMe = false;

if(isset($req->remember_me)) {
    $rememberMe = true;
}

if(Sentinel::authenticate($req->all(), $rememberMe)) {
    $slug = Sentinel::getUser()->roles()->first()->slug();
}
```

The cookies was set, I see it in the chrome settings but it does not do as I expect

I'm using **laravel 5.2**

Comment: Have you tried setting the value of the cookie to the input **`value="{{ cookie('email') }}"`** ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cookies

cookie, is a small piece of data sent from a website and stored in a user's web browser while the user is browsing that website. Every time the user loads the website, the browser sends the cookie back to the server to notify the website of the user's previous activity
To create:

```
$response->withCookie(Cookie::make('name', 'value', $minutes));
```

To retrieve

```
$value = Cookie::get('name');
```

Your question is not to remember the user login.. The question is how to fill the inputs based on saved auth information. You can do that if you print the authentication values in the input value attribute while loading the page.

larval Cookies Docs

Also Laravel has it's own implementation of "Remember Me"

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password), true))
{
// The user is being remembered...
}

if (Auth::viaRemember())
{
//
}
```

More information about https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#remembering-users

Answer (score 0):

There is two main thing need to taken care:
1) You must pass a bool value as second parameter to the method, make sure you cast it before passing it to the method. - In your code, it's perfect

```
$credentials = $req->only('LOGINNAME', 'PASSNAME')
if(Sentinel::authenticate($credentials , $req->has('remember_me'))){
 //Other stuff
}
```

2) you can verify it works by ensuring a cookie is set with the key `cartalyst_sentinel`?

So first change as per 1) option and then check the 2) option, may be this is your answer.